# Adobe-Brackets, Change the default syntax for a file extension

Tags: markdown, adobe-brackets, github-flavored-markdown

I am using the Adobe Brackets text editor.

I can't seem to find an answer for changing the default syntax to be used with certain file extensions (file-ext). In my case, I would like to change the default markdown syntax to instead use the included "Markdown (Github)" syntax. I assumed that there was an option somewhere to control this, as when I go to change the language manually, whilst editing a file, in the selection menu "Markdown" has the word *Default* afterwards.

How can I change the default syntax per file extension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the very top of that "File type selection" there is an option to set the current as default:
[image: Set language Default]

Alternatively, you can map file extensions (and file names) to existing languages in the [preferences](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/wiki/Language-Support#preferences):

```json
{
    "language.fileExtensions": {
        "md": "gfm"
    }
}
```

---

Note: This is valid for at least the latest version of Brackets (1.4).

Comment: Set as Default was not working so must be bugged for me. However your other method of adding languge.fileExtensions to the brackets.json file worked like a charm! Thanks so much!